# Db migrations - Django 1.5 on GAE

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, database-migration

I am new to both: Google Platform and Python/Django, so please forgive me for a silly question.
I am trying to figure out, how can I run sql migrations on Google App Engine ( using Cloud SQL on Google ).

I understand, that I need to launch

```
appcfg.py -A project-name update app.yaml
```

to deploy an app on GAE. But I don't believe it will make any db migrations. So, probably, I should do some extra steps? If yes, when what should I do ( and how )?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Best Regards,
Maksim

Comment: Oh really? Where do you see anything related to django migrations there? mysqldump and/or export/import is not what I am looking for. Maybe you should read the question more carefully before down-voting it?

Comment: Well in this case, you may need to clarify. "db migrations" is something that would be covered by the import/export functionalities. And I never said I downvoted. In fact, I did NOT. I posted something to try to help you out

Comment: Ok, sorry. Was kind of upset to see down-votes and a comment not related to the question at all. Thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I've found a solution here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django

```
SETTINGS_MODE='prod' ./manage.py syncdb
```

Once again, sorry Patrice and thanks.